# jQuery's next() on elements not next to each other

Tags: jquery

I have bits of horrible code I have to deal with

```
...
<div class="container">
   ...
    <tr>
    <td width="100" height="50">
         <a class="swaps"><img src="http://www.blah.jpg" alt="Some Title" id="1"></a></span></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td width="100" height="50">
        <a class="swaps"><img src="http://www.blah2.jpg" alt="Another title" id="2"></a></span></td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

If I use

`var thisone = $("#container .swaps:first")`

to select the first one (with id 1) why do I have trouble selecting

`thisone.next()`?

Comment: are you trying to find the next `<a class="swaps"..` when you call `thisone.next()`?

Comment: yup. The problem with it is that I need to get the next one so that I can iterate through (so that the next one becomes the current one, and the next one's next becomes the next one, etc...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML is the real one? I don't see any element with id "container" and you're doing

`$("#container .swaps:first")`

Also, if it's the real HTML, you should fix it a little (close the img tag, and add the opening tag for the span before the </TD>)

Supposing that your HTML is OK this should work for your scenario.

```
var thisone = $("#container .swaps:first");
thisone.children();
```

The IMG is not sibling of the anchor, is a child.

Comment: That returns a blank, unfortunately...?

Answer (score 1):

Because, as Jquery docs says:

> The :first pseudo-class is equivalent
>   to :eq(0). It could also be written as
>   :lt(1). While this matches only a
>   single element, :first-child can match
>   more than one: One for each parent.

Try using `.children()`
as in `$(selector).children();`

Answer (score 1):

the next() method checks siblings for matches...in your scenario there are no other siblings with .swaps class...try $("#container .swaps")

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `next()` function returns the next sibling as they appear in the DOM tree (not in jQuery resultset) for all matched elements. So calling

```
$("#container .swaps:first")
```

gets the first anchor, and calling `next()` on it returns undefined as it has no next sibling. I think you might want to implement the [Iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern) if you want to access the nodes successively by calling `next()`.

The jQuery object is an array of items. You could just store the current index in a variable, and increment it after getting the next element.

```
// Naive way
var items = $("#container .swaps");
var i = 0;
items[i++] // first <a>
items[i++] // second <a>
```

Here are two implementations that wrap the above functionality using the Iterator pattern - one that works as a jQuery plugin, the other is basically a separate function. Both work the same:

```
// Iterator function
function Iterator(list) {
    var results = list;
    var i = 0;

    this.next = function() {
        return results[i++];
    };

    return this;
}

// Usage
var iterator = Iterator($("#container .swaps"));
iterator.next() // first <a>
iterator.next() // second <a>
```

The second one is almost identical to the first one, but is used a jQuery plugin instead:

```
// jQuery plugin
$.fn.iterator = function() {
    var i = 0;

    this.next = function() {
        return this[i++];
    };

    return this;
};

// Usage
var iterator = $("#container .swaps").iterator();
iterator.next() // first <a>
iterator.next() // second <a>
```

Javascript 1.7 has some cool features in [generators and iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7#Generators) for doing just this, but it's not still not widespread - only Firefox supports it as far as I know.

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `:first`, which cuts the set down to one, so there is no "next". You could try using `:first-child` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `thisone.next()` should actually get nothing because there is no sibling (at the same level) to the original selection.  What you want is the children of `thisone`, that is an img, using `thisone.children("img")`.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector should be

```
var thisone = $("div.container a.swaps:first");
var img = thisone.children(img);
```

Also your id is invalid. You can't start an id with a number.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I know it isn't your code, but IDs should never start with or only contain a number.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but I think it would be easier if you just iterate through all the `.swaps` like this:

```
$('#container .swaps').each(function(){
 var swapImg = $(this).find('img');
 // do something else
})
```