# Jquery each loop with after reference

Tags: jquery, canvas, jquery-selectors

I want to draw a canvas line from .class element to class element. So far I can reference the start and end elements in the class by elements.first() and elements.first().

The difficulty is that I want to use quadraticCurveTo that want a start and endpoint. The end point is the next element in the .class.

```
$('.myclass').chainlines();
$.fn.chainlines = function(){
context.moveTo($(this).first().position().left+15,$(this).first().position().top+20);
$(this).each(function(){
next = $(this).next();
context.quadraticCurveTo($(this).first().position().left+60,
$(this).position().top+25,$(next).position().left+15,$(next).position().top+15);
});
};
```

I have a jsfiddle example that I need to expand into a chained . see [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/joegyoung/rjxsH/).

This isn't working for me.

Comment: I don't see what the linked fiddle has to do with this code snippet. Also, that code snippet is not valid jQuery.

Comment: And what makes you think there is an actual `.id()` method in jQuery, did you try `.prop('id')`

Comment: @adeneo The id is not a property but an attribute.

Comment: @adeneo I'm quite agrre with Juhana, btw, 'id' should always keep default value, so no reason to use .prop() here. But for 'id', that's a wrong debate as we should use property of DOM element instead

Comment: @roasted, so you're suggesting to use `element.getAttribute('id')` over `element.id`? because that's the difference between `$(..).attr('id')` and `$(..).prop('id')`. Both `prop` and `attr` should work just fine, but I'd stick with `prop` for consistency.

Comment: ID, as written in the HTML, would be an attribute. I'd just as well get the elements ID property.

Comment: @zzzzBov no, Im suggesting to use element.id over anything else. And if for some reason you have to use jquery (chaining?), i'm suggesting to use .attr() instead of .prop() because ID should not be a changing variable but always keep as default value

Comment: @roasted, `attr` can be used to set a value the same way `prop` can. `attr(key)` is the jQuery version of `element.getAttribute(key)` while `prop(key)` is the jQuery version of `element[key]`, so if you'd use `element.id`, you should use `prop('id')` for consistency.

Comment: @zzzzBov Ok, i got your POV, seems fair now. Thanx.

Comment: OK. I found that I may not be able to use next . [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589755/jquerys-next-on-elements-not-next-to-each-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fiddle seems to have nothing to do with your question...

I think you're looking for something like this..

```
 divs.each(function(idx){
    alert(divs[idx].next().attr("id"));
 })
```

Comment: Why not use 'this' instead of divs[idx] ?

Comment: @roasted [Accessing by index is much faster](http://jsperf.com/so-hgwr-gu) although in this case it probably isn't noticeable.

Comment: @Juhana you are suggesting access by index is faster than using referenced object 'this', that's interesting, i'd test it to see what's going on.

Comment: That jsperf compares apples and oranges. `$(this) !== a[i]` Here's the proper comparison: http://jsperf.com/so-hgwr-gu/2 the difference is too small to matter.

Comment: @roasted I assume it's because you need to create a new jQuery object (`$(this)`) every time instead of re-using an existing one.

Comment: @KevinB It's a different jQuery object but of the same DOM element and practically the same thing. (edit: ah ok, I see what you mean.)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting feedback... I think the array index is definitely faster.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is what you are looking for:

```
divs.each(function(){
   alert($(this).next().get(0).id);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem

```
$.fn.chainlines = function(){
    var divs = $(this);
    var count = $(this).length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if((i + 1) < count){
            context.moveTo($(divs[i]).position().left+15,$(divs[i]).position().top+20);
            context.quadraticCurveTo($(divs[i]).position().left+60,
                                 $(divs[i]).position().top+35,
                                 $(divs[i+1]).position().left+15,
                                 $(divs[i+1]).position().top+1);      
            context.stroke();
        }
    }
};
```